# Unable to export AVMutableComposition using AVAssetExportSession only on iOS7 swift

Tags: swift, ios7, avfoundation

I'm trying to export an AVMutableComposition using AVAssetExportSession to a mp4 file in NSTemporaryDirectory(). It works great on iOS8 but on iOS7 I got a -1100 error on exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

My composition contains 2 AVAssets, both getting sources from the web, one for the video, one for the audio.

At first, I though that this was a folder problem but I can create / delete a file using NSFileManager without trouble.

I don't really understand why it should work on iOS8 but not on iOS7 and I didn't spot any particular "introduced=8.0"

Here is my code:

```
func compose() {
    var composition = AVMutableComposition()
    var videoTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    var audioTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    var videoAsset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(videoUrl) as! AVAsset //Not a local URL
    var audioAsset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(audioUrl) as! AVAsset //Not a local URL

    var videoTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration)
    var videoError: NSError?
    if let tracks = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(mediaType) as? [AVMediaTypeVideo] where tracks.isEmpty == false {
       videoTrack.insertTimeRange(videoTimeRange, ofTrack: tracks[0], atTime: duration, error: &videoError)
    }

    var audioTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration)
    var audioError: NSError?
    if let tracks = audioAsset.tracksWithMediaType(mediaType) as? [AVMediaTypeAudio] where tracks.isEmpty == false {
       audioTrack.insertTimeRange(audioTimeRange, ofTrack: tracks[0], atTime: duration, error: &audioError)
    }

    self.export(composition)
}

func export(composition: AVMutableComposition) {
    self.exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality)
    let filename = "composition.mp4"
    let outputPath = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(filename)

    //Check if file already exists and delete it if needed
    if let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath) {
       let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
       if manager.fileExistsAtPath(outputPath) {
          var error: NSError? = nil
          if manager.removeItemAtPath(outputPath, error: &error) == true {
               println("Removed")
           }
        }

       //File should be 30 seconds max
       let maxDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(30.0, composition.duration.timescale)
       let exportInterval = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, maxDuration)

       self.exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
       self.exporter.outputURL = fileUrl
       self.exporter.timeRange = exportInterval

       self.exporter.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({ () -> Void in
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
               if self.exporter.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed {
                   println("Success")
               }
               else {
                   println(self.exporter.error?.localizedDescription)
                   //The requested URL was not found on this server.
               }
           })
       })
}
```

I'm getting stuck on this problem for a while now, so any advice would be much appreciated !

Thanks in advance,

Cordially, Louis.

Edit 7th July:

I found out that it is not possible to do so since AVMutableComposition does not support web URLs in iOS7.

For now, I haven't been able to find a workaround and would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: "The requested URL was not found on this server" Which line of your code generates that error?

Comment: @matt I got the error from the exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler (see the "else" comment)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm running into something similar with iOS9.

Comment: Hi @socca1157,
No I did not and won't ever since I dropped it a few month ago
Furthermore, I only had this while running on iOS7, never the later versions